# can we create asp 5 application in mac OS X without using mono?

Tags: macos, mono, asp.net-core, coreclr

I have tried to create and run a new asp 5 web application in command line successfully with using mono. but while study on some other blog, mono not primarily supported for windows and also coreClr will support all platforms like windows, mac, linux.

if so, can we create an web application in MAC with using .NET core alone (coreClr) ?

is coreClr building was completed for all platforms ?

-Guru

Comment: Sure... coreclr @ https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr) & asp.net 5 @ https://github.com/aspnet/home... Not sure what you mean by Mono is not support on Windows...

Comment: @SushiHangover - thanks for info. but in [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/choosing-the-right-dotnet.html), as they informed like mono is not supported by windows.

is any difference in mono and coreClr in compilation or command line changes to create and execute an web application ?

Answer (score 2):

I got it running on a Mac-Mini without Mono: http://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2015/12/14/run-aspnet5-on-mac.html
Just go to http://get.asp.net/, download and install the package and follow the instructions.

Comment: is .dnx location created for your machine ? can i know how to find the .dnx location for .NET Core installed machine ? I tried, ~/.dnx in my end but there is no such folder

Comment: do you installed any version of dnx on your machine? type 'dnvm list' to see the installed version.

Comment: yeah, dnvm all are installed properly. can you look on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781977/how-to-find-the-dnx-location-in-mac-which-have-net-core-alone-without-mono