# How to find the .dnx location in mac which have .NET core alone (without mono)

Tags: macos, mono, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have installed .NET Core alone (without mono) in my mac book. But i unable to find the .dnx location in my machine. I tried the following command **~/.dnx**, but there no folder is available, i tried with another machine with have mono, in there, such folder is available. Really i don't know why difference in .dnx location between mono and .NET core installed machine ?

I need to place a custom package in .dnx location for testing purpose instead hosting in nuget.org. How to achieve this scenario in .NET core installed MacBook ?

-Guru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run `dnvm list -Detailed` to also show the location of the installed dnx runtimes. On Windows dnx is installed in the current users folder. Maybe it is in a similar location on the mac.